# sbt scala language server server crashed 5 times in last 3 minutes. The server will not be restarted

Tags: scala, sbt, visual-studio-code

I have installed Visual Studio code 1.18.1 on my mac book pro.

I also installed the Scala (SBT) plugin as instructed in this blog.

https://developer.lightbend.com/blog/2017-11-30-sbt-1-1-0-RC1-sbt-server/

Now when I restart visual studio code. I get an error

```
The sbt Scala Language Server server crashed 5 times in the last 3 minutes. The server will not be restarted.
```

Has anyone got it to work at all?

BTW, I followed this blog

http://eed3si9n.com/sbt-server-with-sublime-text3

and the SBT server worked perfectly in Sublime. So I want to know if the same can work in VSCode or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK. I asked for help on the sbt gitter channel and found the solution.

My SBT server was already running when VSCode was run. I restarted both of them and that solved the problem.